# Limit on using google geocoder API

Tags: google-geocoder

I am using this geocoder API to get the geocodes of an address. Thing is that there is no API key in this API. Will google block me after certain requests or not ?

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=

Answer (score 1):

The use of a key with the Google Maps Geocoding API is mandatory, it doesn´t matter if the free limit is not reached, your requests could still be blocked at some point.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

> To use the Google Maps Geocoding API, you need an API key.

Answer (score 0):

It is free to use, but they limit both the request rate and the total requests per day. You can pay more to have those limits lifted. More details can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits